# adls storage to adls storage file transfer

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, azcopy

Trying to send files using a remote on-premises server and azcopy from one ADLS storage account to another storage account(weird requirement but needed).

```
azcopy cp 'https://mysourceaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer?sxxxxxx' 'https://mydestinationaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer' --recursive
```

throws an error saying below:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include formatted text for your error output, not images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my environment and it is working for me Please use the below formatted command (You were missing SAS token for second container and –recursive=true)

```
azcopy copy "https://tstadlsstorage1.dfs.core.windows.net/testcontainer?SAS_token_for_container_in_source_storageaccount" "https://tstadlsstorage2.dfs.core.windows.net/testcontainer2?SAS_token_for_container_in_destination_storageaccount"
--recursive=true
```

[image]

Output--

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error after using both sas keys of the container. ERROR: Please check the parameters you supplied.  If they are correct, please specify an exact source and destination type using the --from-to switch.  Use the word 'Blob' for Blob Storage, 'Local' for the local file system, 'File' for Azure Files, and 'BlobFS' for ADLS Gen2. If you need a combination that is not supported yet, please log an issue on the AzCopy GitHub issues list.
failed to parse user input due to error: the inferred source/destination combination could not be identified or is currently not supported.

Comment: Did you tried with what exactly i have given in command? Use " " if you are using ' ' in a command.